# Text boxes loading out of position and jumping on page

Tags: html, css, liquid

https://454ykcyas2noa7qt-2236153955.shopifypreview.com/

Notice how as the page loads, the text boxes that sit over top of the images (the ones with white background "You know that feeling…" and "We recommend you keep a pair handy") load first and then get pushed down the page into position as the rest of the images load? I'm wondering how I can stop this from happening?

[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uEmI.jpg)

Comment: I couldn't see that. Anyway, to avoid that you can add `width` and `height` Html attributes to `img` elements.

Comment: Thanks, I added a screenshot so you can see what I mean. The issue with setting the width and height is that it moves around with the screen size, and I'll be regularly updating the text and therefore the size if the box